# ¿Cómo encontrar un objeto por sus atributos y al encontrarlo variar alguno de sus atributos en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, filtro

Quisiera obtener el objeto que coincida por su cod_group y su categoría(para filtrarlo) y luego poder cambiarle el atributo sueldo sumandole un valor x, realmente filtrar e identificarlo para poder actualizar el valor de su atributo, espero me apoyen gracias :D.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cod_group":14,
    "name": "Trabajador 1",
    "sueldo": 500,
    "categoria": "cat2",
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "cod_group": 15,
    "name": "trabajador 2",
    "sueldo": 500,
    "secretIdentity": "cat3",
  }
]
```

Comment: Puedes buscar su posición con [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) y luego acceder con `arreglo[indice].sueldo` para consultar o modificar.

Comment: En mi caso el indice de cada objeto es volatil, cambia constantemente así que no sé si es la mejor opción en este caso ya que solo identifica la posición si no mal recuerdo o tambien permite filtrar por condiciones?

Comment: Usa array.find (si es sólo uno) o array.filter (si pueden ser varios) para quedarte con los elementos que cumplan la condición

Comment: Sí,`.findIndex()` te devuelve la posición del primer elemento que cumpla con las condiciones especificadas. ¿Leíste el manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar el empleado podrias usar un array.find() para identificar, luego de ello si el empleado existe, modificar una propiedad en concreto (sueldo) del empleado y devolverlo a su conjunto de datos. A continuación una explicación más grafica. Espero te sirva! :D

```
 'use strict'
    var data = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "cod_group":14,
        "name": "Trabajador 1",
        "sueldo": 500,
        "categoria": "cat2",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "cod_group": 15,
        "name": "trabajador 2",
        "sueldo": 500,
        "secretIdentity": "cat3",
      }
    ]

//funcion para acutalizar el sueldo
const actualizarSueldo = (codigoGrupoTrabajador, categoriaTrabajador, nuevoSueldo) => {
    //creamos un arreglo vacio el cual será nuestro alacenador de empleados actualizados,
    //esto con el fin de evitar la mutabilidad de los datos.
    var empleadosActualizados = [];
    //buscamos si existe el empleado que buscamos en el JSON
    var existeEmpleado = data.find( (emp) =>  
        emp.cod_group === codigoGrupoTrabajador
        && emp.categoria === categoriaTrabajador
    );

    //si es que existe el empleado...
    if(existeEmpleado){
        //modificamos: dejamos todas sus propiedades intactas, excepto el sueldo 
        //{...todasSusPropiedadesQuedanIgual, sueldo: valorQueLePasemosALaFuncion}
        existeEmpleado = { ...existeEmpleado, sueldo: nuevoSueldo };
        //una vez modificamos la propiedad de sueldo del empleado, ordenamos las cosas tal cual las recibimos
        //pero actualizadas.
        //recorremos nuestro arreglo original e idenficamos al empleado que modificamos, si lo encuentra
        //es reemplazado por el actualizado, si no, le devuelve al arreglo el empleado en la posicion actual.
        empleadosActualizados = data.map( empleado => empleado.id == existeEmpleado.id ? existeEmpleado : empleado);
        return empleadosActualizados;
    }else{
        return "no se encontró el empleado";
    };

}
console.log(actualizarSueldo(14, "cat2", 123));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo y molestia, le logré entender a la perfección y logré mi objetivo, nuevamente agradecido con el conocimiento compartido.

Comment: No es ninguna molestia bro, al contrario. Cuidese, buen finde! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes hacer un forEach y comparar por los datos que quieras comparar y lo puedes poner en una función para que lo puedas utilizar donde quieras.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cod_group":14,
    "name": "Trabajador 1",
    "sueldo": 500,
    "categoria": "cat2",
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "cod_group": 15,
    "name": "trabajador 2",
    "sueldo": 500,
    "secretIdentity": "cat3",
  }
]

function BuscarObjeto(codGroup, categoria) {

            let obj = null;

            json.forEach(function (o) {
                if (o.cod_group == codGroup && o.categoria == categoria) {
                    obj = o;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return obj;
        }
        
 let encontrado = BuscarObjeto(14, "cat2");
 document.write(JSON.stringify(encontrado))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte estimado, fue muy útil la forma en a cual me apoyaste.